# TextInputLayout hint color for various states

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

I have been trying to customize the Hint color in TextInputLayout and it works fine. But the problem is that I have to define color when there is an error, normal/Activated which is working and disabled state of the field.

So I tried creating three different styles with color normal, color activated and so on. But this doesn't seem to change the colour. I have indicated the Appcombat theme as the parent theme as well in my custom styles. I have tried applying these styles through java file as well.

Also let me know on how to define the size of the Hint text through style.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but here goes my solution to this:

Set the same style in `errorTextAppearance` and `hintTextAppearance`, both with the same color for the item `android:textColor`. When showing an error, set the error using a spannable with a `ForegroundColorSpan` with the color you wish to display in the error field, while the hint will remain in the color defined by the style set in `errorTextAppearance`.